# Phantom Group Membership in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I have a long-running application that uses FederatedAuthentication with Azure AD to manage claims-based identities. My application manifest is set to list all SecurityGroups for a user (so I can walk the list of groups they are members of).

Within that application I have a user that is a member of a single top-level group. That group is not a member of any other. Previously, when the user logged in, there would be only a single `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups` value attached to their ClaimsPrincipal, correctly displaying the single group they are a member of.

As of recently (past few days) when my user logs in, there are two `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups` values. One of these still corresponds to the group they are a member of, but the new one does not match the id of any visible group in my active directory (or any other object that I can see: no application ID, and no other user ID).

Where could this phantom group membership have come from, and is there any way I can remove it?

**Update** - `groupMembershipClaims` in the Application manifest is set to `SecurityGroup` (not `All`).

Comment: Has the user been added to another tenant in AAD? Or have they recently started using another product with their username, like VSTS?

Comment: @RickvandenBosch Recently logging in to a new app. Not assigned to another tenant that I know of (I can check). Would membership of another tenant show up in groups?

Comment: Not sure, just trying to get all the details ;)

Comment: If you have `groupMemberShipClaims: "All"` in your app manifest, it could also be an Office 365 group/mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @juunas, that's useful. He hasn't knowingly been added to such a list (and certainly not in this directory, which isn't connected to Office365 at all - it's pure Azure), but he might have used SSO to another app that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing , the group claims will return a collection of the Groups and DirectoryRoles that current user is a member of , the result is similar to use `memberOf` azure ad graph api :

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/$links/memberOf?api-version
```

The result with above api:
[image]

Even if i set `groupMembershipClaims` to `SecurityGroup` , i get the same three records(2 groups and 1 directory role) in my token with group claims . My account is a global administrator in my AAD . If i set the account to user directory role(non admin role) , then i only get two group records in my group claims .

With azure ad graph api , to get all of the groups that the user has direct or transitive membership in, we could call the [getMemberGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups) function.

If you want group claims only return groups that the user has direct or transitive membership in , you could send your feedback in [AAD userVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?query=assignments) .

Comment: This makes sense. The user did recently become a global administrator for the directory. That's not a group, though, so I couldn't see how that could have any effect (and it does seem a bit buggy that his role is returned in a list specifically called "groups" - whereas the `memberOf` functionality seems correct). He doesn't need to be an admin, in fact, so I should be able to fix it easily. Many thanks.