# azure active directory - weird group membership issue with users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a bug with the azure process for adding users to groups in azure active directory ?  I have 2 groups, one is admin, the other standard user.  If I put a user in the admin group, when I look at claimsidentity for that user after theyve successfully logged into my app, I see 2 groups, which I would expect If they are an admin user.  If I remove that user from admin and make them a standard user, after logging in I can still see 2 groups in their claimsIdentity object.  I then remove then from ALL group membership and I can after logging in again, I can see 1 group in the claimsidentiy object.  The claimsidentity simply isnt reflecting the groups the user is a member of, its a mess.  How is security supposed to work If I cant even accuratley determine the group a user belongs to.  So Im currently logging in as a user IN NO GROUP MEMBERSHIP and the claimsidenty object is showing 1 group (standard user)  what the heck is going on ??

Answer (score 0):

As i said in your [previous case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175688/how-to-determine-which-group-a-user-is-a-member-of-in-azure-active-directory) .The group claims will return a collection of the **Groups and DirectoryRoles** that current user is a member of . I believe the user has a DirectoryRole (not a user) such as `Global administrator` in your AAD .

To confirm that , in Azure portal--> your AAD-->Users and groups - All users-->select that user -->Directory role--> choose `User` . After that , you will only get the groups that current user is a member of . See more details from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45229808/5751404) .

If you to want to get all of the groups(no DirectoryRoles) that the user has direct or transitive membership in , we could call the [getMemberGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups) function using Azure AD Graph API .

If you want the group claims only return Groups that current user is a member of . You could send a feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) .